# JavaScript/JSON Interface Description Language

Tags: javascript, metadata

Take as example [MDN Spider Monkey Parser API web page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Parser_API). You can see that an object returned by a Javascript method is described by a meta-language. The following snippet in that page:

```
interface Node {
  type: string;
  loc: SourceLocation | null;
}
```

Describes an object called `Node` which has two properties: `type` and `loc`. And the following:

```
interface Program <: Node {
  type: "Program";
  body: [ Statement ];
}
```

Describes another object which will inherit properties `type` and `loc` from `Node` plus will have property `body`.

### About this meta-language

This meta-language is obviously used for documentation purposes as Javascript is not typed, it can get quite tricky to understand what an object exposes when having to deal with it.

**Example** For example, if I had to document a Javascript object consisting of 3 members: a string, an array of ints and a function, I might go something like:

```
interface MyObject {
  path: string;
  indices: [int];
  evaluateScore: function;
}
```

This is a clever way to document Javascript objects exposing certain API! But cannot find a standard here!

**Questions** I want to know more about this meta-language, but cannot find resources in Internet. However, in order to make this question *answerable* and not too generic, as starters, please consider the following questions:

1. Does this meta-language have a name?
2. Is this a possible IDL for JavaScript/JSON?
3. Does this meta-language have an official specification?
4. If a specification is present, where can i find it?

Thanks

### Note

Please note that this question is not about ASTs. **I do not care about them**! The page I linked just happens to be about ASTs, but that is because I could not find another web page or library documenting their JS stuff using such a meta-language. I just want to know more about the meta-language used by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) in that page to document their JavaScript objects and what API they expose.

Answer (score 1):

I too spent quite some time looking for a specification, or some kind of description for this format. A few projects seem to be using this type of IDL for documentation of an AST, including Babel, Handlebars, and ESTree.

I found [this](https://github.com/estree/estree/issues/133) issue on the ESTree github repository that states it is a custom syntax. I wonder if this is true, since it seems strange that so many large projects would decide to use an undocumented syntax like this.