# What mean `<:` symbol in ESTree AST definition?

Tags: javascript

What mean `<:` symbol in ESTree AST definition

example:

```
interface Identifier <: Expression, Pattern {
    type: "Identifier";
    name: string;
}
```

[link to estree repo](https://github.com/estree/estree/blob/master/es5.md#node-objects)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it signifies inheritance. So, `Identifier` inherits from `Expression` and `Pattern`

Comment: I'd guess "subtype", "extends" or "implements", but it definitely appears to be [custom non-standard syntax](https://github.com/estree/estree#ast-descriptor-syntax)

Comment: related, if not duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55060072/what-language-is-used-to-describe-an-abstract-syntax-tree-in-estree https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191890/javascript-json-interface-description-language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the `Identifier` is a *subtype* of `Expression` and `Pattern`. So any identifier will also be of the other types as well.

It doesn't mean exactly the same as *inheritance*, but you could interprete it as this in this context.

Answer (score 2):

It means "inheritance". Take a look into `Expression` and `Pattern`:

```
interface Expression <: Node { }
interface Pattern <: Node { }
```

Both of them extends from a regular `Node`:

```
interface Node {
    type: string;
    loc: SourceLocation | null;
}
```

So in case with `Identifier` it means "take all the properties from Expression and Pattern and add to them these properties":

```
interface Identifier <: Expression, Pattern {
    type: "Identifier"; // Node has a property "type" which is string
    name: string;
    loc: SourceLocation | null // Node has a property "loc" so as an Identifier here
}
```